# How to manage netflix-conductor workflow versions in github

Tags: version-control, workflow, conductor, netflix-conductor

I am currently exploring netflix-conductor for an orchestration application. And I want to manage the workflow and task definitions outside the conductor DB (github) and allow for everyone to contribute to modify the workflows and deploy them to dev, uat and prod environments when scheduled. Is there any advice on how I can do that?

Comment: Recently learned that netflix has decommissioned conductor